# Как связать id одной колонки с другой Posthresql NestJS

Tags: postgresql, nestjs

```
import {
  Entity,
  PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
  Column,
  OneToOne,
  JoinColumn,
  OneToMany,
} from 'typeorm';
import { Image } from './image.entity';

@Entity()
export class Laptop {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'laptopId' })
  title: string;

  @Column()
  price: number;

  @OneToMany(() => Image, (image) => image.laptop)
  imagePaths: Image[];

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column()
  characteristicScreen: string;

  @Column()
  characteristicProcessor: string;
}
мне нужно связать   @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
вот это 
import { Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column, ManyToOne } from 'typeorm';
import { Laptop } from './laptop.entity';

@Entity()
export class Image {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  imagePath: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Laptop, (laptop) => laptop.imagePaths)
  laptop: Laptop;

  @Column({ name: 'laptopId' })
  laptopId: number;
}
```

тут с laptopId что я делаю не так